# Binding value as html in stenciljs

Tags: javascript, html-parsing, stenciljs

I am having trouble rendering a value with custom html inside into an element.
ex:

```
this.title = 'Hello <b> stencil </b>'; << response value from an API
```

**Binding:**

```
<h1>{this.title}</h1>
```

> I am expecting something same as **innerHtml** behavior in JavaScript.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use

```
<h1 innerHTML={this.title} />
```

Comment: I tried it before but did not work, I don't know how it did now, maybe a new version update fixed it. Thank you

Comment: Actually it was added in a new release :D

Answer (score -2):

This is not a good practice in JSX, it is against the idea of virtual DOM and it's not creating virtual nodes.

**You should try like this**

```
this.salute = 'Hello';
this.name='stencil';
```

Binding

`<h1>{this.salute} <b>{this.name}</b></h1>`

Or if it is a more complex situation, build another smaller component.

However using `innerHTML` will work, but should be used in different situations more details [here(at the bottom of the page)](https://stenciljs.com/docs/templating-jsx/).

Comment: The title value is coming from a server response

Comment: This shouldn't have been down-voted imo. While it doesn't answer the question as-asked, it does highlight that the question is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and the solution is actually "don't put HTML in your content if you can avoid it".
Allowing HTML in the content you pull from the server is a slippery slope: what happens when that HTML is invalid? Sure, there are cases where it can't be avoided, but those should be the exception -- not the rule. This answer does a good job of explaining that.

Comment: yes this answer should be upvoted. This question could be an security issue, look here:
https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/116.html